# Toggle between two image does not work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having 8 images overlapped one over other in `svg` file format. It resemble like tab menu bar.I have a tab for billing when that tab is active all other tab must be found behind and If I click another tab like employee that tab must be active and other tab must be inactive. I need to toggle between two images. Hence I tried out with this code.

```css
.gold1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gold8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script>
  jQuery("#infoToggler").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('img').toggle();
});
</script>
<img src="gray2.svg" class="gray2">
<img src="gray3.svg" class="gray3">
<img src="gray4.svg" class="gray4">
<img src="gray5.svg" class="gray5">
<img src="gray6.svg" class="gray6">
<img src="gray7.svg" class="gray7">
<img src="gray8.svg" class="gray8">
<div id="infoToggler">
  <img src="gold1.svg" class="gold1" />

  <img src="gray1.svg" class="gray1" style="display:none/>

</div>
```

Can someone help me code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the jsFiddle you provided in your first comment I have updated it to look similar to yours.

here is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/372/ and Html/Css/jQuery code

HTML

```
<div id="infoToggler">
    <img src="gold1.svg" class="image1" />
    <img src="gray1.svg" class="image2" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image1 {
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.image2 {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#infoToggler").click(function () {
        $(this).find('img').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: My image becomes hidden it do not toggle again? :(

Comment: That works fine for me. Now i need to have many tabs similarly how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach. You need to toggle between 2 images. I don't see where you apply the toggle to 2 images.

Most simple is this: by click: hide all and display the clicked one.

Comment: How could I perform that? I need to replace a image over another. I just referred  this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/91/

Comment: Make 1 background image in a block element (div, etc.). Put your images in this block. Position the images with css. So you can toggle an image. By clicking an image, set all images in block to display none. After that, set clicked image to active. No need to replace, because the use of a background image.

Comment: You have not closed your function properly